# leaflet: get driving directions

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there a way to get driving directions between two markers on a leaflet map? I am coding with javascript and use mapbox for layers. I can't find any method or sth.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nothing is impossible.. But some things could take longer time/procedure ... :)

Comment: This is primarily a feature of the Google Maps JavaScript API, but a MapQuest plugin exists for routing/directions for Leaflet: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/plugins/leaflet/v1.0/routing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of plugins which request directions from different providers, like this one https://github.com/Turistforeningen/leaflet-routing

On plugins listing page there are another couple of them http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html

If you're using Mapbox, you can use Mapbox directions https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions.js

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/), the Open Source Routing Machine. It's a static web application based on Leaflet that has a very fast routing interface. You obviously need to connect it to a routing server, but fortunately there is a free one available for car-based routing. Alternatively you can run your own.

There's a demo at http://map.project-osrm.org/ .

Comment: Is it possible with this library to provide audio turn by turn directions when driving?  Using a PWA?